# how to handle overflow while implementing profiling

Tags: c, arm, cortex-m

I am trying to find the time which is consumed by a given block of code in ARM processor. For that I am using Systick timer which is basically a down-counter.

For a normal block of code, i can measure time difference between start of function and end of function to know the time measured. However, if the piece of code is too long, how should I handle it?

According to my logic I will use the formula devised by me as shown:

```
time consumed=(no. of times overflow occured X start value)
 +(start value - end value)
```

P.S: The start value is the maximum value and not zero since the timer is down counter.

Is my reasoning correct or should I use some other formula?

Answer (score 0):

The formula should be correct, provided that you take into account the maximum number of ticks done in a cycle.

Say the number of ticks in a full cycle is `MAX_TICKS`, then the time (in ticks) is

```
nUnderflows * MAX_TICKS + start - end
```

In C, that could be seen as, for instance

```
#define MAX_TICKS 32768

int nUnderflows;

// schematic function called by the system every tick
// (in a critical section)
void systick_callback() {
    if ( ! internal_counter--) {
       internal_counter = MAX_TICKS;
       nUnderflows++;
    }
}

int main() {
   int start,end;

   // small critical section to avoid a race condition
   block_interruptions(); // CLI
   nUnderflows = 0;
   start = systick();
   release_interruptions(); // STI

   my_timed_function();

   end = systick();
   int time = (nUnderflows * MAX_TICKS) + start - end;
   // * precedence is usually higher than of + / -, though
}
```

provided `int` is usable in your case, and doesn't overflow.

Answer (score 0):

if it is a free running counter first off you need to insure the start-end (or end-start depending on down or up counting).  so if it were a 16 bit counter  (start-end)&0xFFFF would be part of the equation.  Then number of overflows times 0x10000 would be part of it and if start

if the timer is a full 32 bits then you dont need a mask although the optimizer should take care of it, as a habit though you should remember if you dont mask then the start-end will produce the wrong number throwing everything off, many rollovers or not.

Answer (score 0):

The [Cortex documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0553a/Babieigh.html) says this is a 24-bit timer that counts down from a value stored in a port called SYST_RVR. (I guess that's what you mean by "start value". It's better to use documented terms when asking questions like this.) When the value transitions from 1 to 0, a systick  interrupt is generated, the SYST_RVR is reset, and the cycle repeats.

The SYST_RVR value, interrupt handler, etc. are up to the OS of the system where your processor lives, which you didn't mention, so there's no way to answer your question in general.

This kind of timer architecture is typically used by the OS to implement a system heartbeat for time-related functions like thread preemption. But there's no standard pattern.

Apparently you know the OS value of SYST_RVR. This establishes the rate of timer expirations. In systems where the timer has been calibrated, there's another register SYST_CALIB that stores the value needed for 10ms between expirations. Maybe your system uses that? Which means you have only 10ms between zeros.

Your formula is fine.

The "number of overflows (actually they're underflows)" is probably the hard part. How are you going to determine that? There appear to be only two ways: 1) intercept the systick interrupt and use that to increment your own counter. Or maybe the existing interrupt handler already keeps a counter. Then you can just measure change in that value.  Option 2): you can insert profiling points in the code you're measuring that records timer values `profile_buffer[++bufp] = <systick value>`. You'd need to insert enough of these to be sure they're no more than 10ms apart (or whatever the actual countdown time is). Then you can analyze the buffer contents after the code is done running to determine total run time. Of course adding test code will increase the run time. But the systick interrupt handler may have the same problem depending on how it's implemented.